performance issue with rtl8156b-2 USB3 2.5 Gbit adapter
https://www.google.com/search?q=Axagon+USB-A+3.2+Gen1+2.5+Gigabit
https://www.google.com/search?q=rtl8156b-2+ubuntu+24
root@laptop:~# ethtool enxc0eac36156XX|egrep "Speed|Duplex"
    Speed: 2500Mb/s
    Duplex: Full
root@laptop:~# 
root@laptop:~# lsb_release -r
No LSB modules are available.
Release:    24.04
root@laptop:~# 
root@laptop:~# apt install linux-oem-24.04 inxi
...
root@laptop:~# inxi -n|grep Realtek
  Device-3: Realtek USB 10/100/1G/2.5G LAN driver: r8152 type: USB
root@laptop:~# 
root@laptop:~# uname -a
Linux laptop 6.8.0-31-generic #31-Ubuntu SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Sat Apr 20 00:40:06 UTC 2024 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
root@laptop:~# 
root@laptop:~# reboot
...
root@laptop:~# uname -a
Linux laptop 6.8.0-1005-oem #5-Ubuntu SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Sat Apr 20 01:33:14 UTC 2024 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
root@laptop:~# 
root@laptop:~# modinfo r8152
filename:       /lib/modules/6.8.0-1005-oem/kernel/drivers/net/usb/r8152.ko.zst
version:        v1.12.13
...

I can only see about ~15 MByte/s from this USB3 adapter over SSHFS.
Previously I used a 1 Gbit USB3 adapter, that could do ~30 MByte/s.
I can see others had issues with this 2.5 Gbit adapter on previous Ubuntu versions..
Question: how to get much bigger bandwidth from this 2.5 Gbit adapter on Ubuntu 24?
Using the "linux-oem-24.04" package and
rmmod cdc_mbim
rmmod cdc_ncm
service udev restart

clearly doesn't helps, since Ubuntu 24 already uses the r8152 driver.

Can you test using iperf3, to rule out other bottlenecks such as encryption and disk?

Also include output of lsusb -t

inxi shows the driver r8152 already. why "lsusb -t" needed?

everything is on SSD and it is clear that it is not an encryption or disk issue.

but thanks for all the advices/points, i will reconsider checking all!!

lsusb -t will show what speed it's attached to USB bus at. Please run the iperf3 test as well, to rule out other bottlenecks.
